# Откуда взять 'OAuth redirect_uri' для инстаграма? Register new Cliend ID

Tags: python, api, instagram, instagram-api

Здравствуйте, хочу сделать бота для социальной активности и повышения уровня культуры в городе. Для этого мне нужно ввести мой веб сайт. Смотрел ссылку http://support.heateor.com/how-to-get-instagram-client-id/ и ничего не понял по-поводу плагина в WebsiteURI,а также Valid redirect URIs и Privacy Policy URL. Буду очень признателен, если вы мне объясните, как работать с ними.